# Java exception when spring loading context configuration file - occurs in UNIX but not Windows

Tags: java, spring, unix, exception, maven

I've been stuck with this one for a while now. I have created a mini subset of the project where this occurs and reproduced the issue. Basically I'm running a test which loads a spring context file with one bean into an ClassPathXmlApplicationContext object.

The weird thing is, on Windows, my test passes fine when run from an IDE (Eclipse/Intellij) and also when I run through maven command line. It fails when the test is run from a UNIX machine (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5) (and this is where the code will inevitable end up).

In the exception below it complains about the LookUtils class. I can't see why it's trying to create this class but one thing I noticed about it was that it has a private constructor. Also, I'm using spring v2.5.6 and have to stick with this for a security reason. I'm pretty stuck with this one so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Here is the exception:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: StartupTest.AppTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.458 sec <<< FAILURE!
testGuiStartup(StartupTest.AppTest)  Time elapsed: 0.43 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lookAndFeelConfigurer' defined in class path resource [startup-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (2) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'popupDropShadowEnabled' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
PropertyAccessException 2: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'theme' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at StartupTest.AppTest.testGuiStartup(AppTest.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (2) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'popupDropShadowEnabled' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
PropertyAccessException 2: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'theme' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    ... 44 more
```

Here is my test:

```
package StartupTest;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AppTest {
    @Test
    public void testGuiStartup() {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("startup-context.xml");
    }
}
```

Here is my context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="lookAndFeelConfigurer" class="org.springframework.richclient.application.config.JGoodiesLooksConfigurer">
        <property name="popupDropShadowEnabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="theme">
            <bean class="com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.theme.ExperienceRoyale"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>StartupTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>StartupTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>StartupTest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
            <artifactId>looks</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.richclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-richclient-support</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: It looks like the jgoodies looks library is not in the classpath.

Comment: But if it's added as a maven dependency surely it is automatically added to the classpath? How can confirm this/resolve this?

Comment: Oh sorry. I misread the question and thought you got this at runtime, and not when executing unit tests.

Comment: The only difference I can see between Windows and Unix is that Unix is case sensitive. So double check your classpath.

Comment: How exactly do I do this? I can echo $CLASSPATH on the unix server which comes out as a blank line and then doing the same in windows I see: .; followed by some IBM jars which I don't think are relevant.

Comment: You have a NoClassDefFoundError on com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils
 so Spring cannot resolve the jar jgoodies. How are you testing your app on Unix? To debug the classpath, generate the .classpath file with Maven http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952846/generating-classpath-file-with-maven

Comment: how do you run this test on unix?

Comment: I run using: 
mvn clean install

The output for  mvn dependency:build-classpath was:

[INFO] Dependencies classpath:
/var/tmp/collinci/repository/com/jgoodies/looks/2.0.4/looks-2.0.4.jar:/var/tmp/collinci/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/var/tmp/collinci/repository/junit/junit/4.8/junit-4.8.jar:/var/tmp/collinci/repository/org/springframework/spring/2.5.6/spring-2.5.6.jar:/var/tmp/collinci/repository/org/springframework/richclient/spring-richclient-support/0.2.1/spring-richclient-support-0.2.1.jar

Comment: I can see LookUtils in looks-2.0.4.jar so it is on the classpath :(

Comment: Also I tried upgrading to spring 3.1.0.RELEASE just to see if it would help... same error :(

Comment: Have you checked the versions of Java on the various machines?  All the same?

Comment: Yes, both are set to jdk v1.6.0_33

Comment: Also tried upgrading to jgoodies looks-2.2.2 with no luck

Comment: Try cleaning out your local artifact repository on the machine with the error.  Sometimes weird errors like this are caused by a corrupted artifact in a local repo.

Comment: Tried cleaning local repository. Same error.

Comment: Still stuck on this... not good for my job security. Any further help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. Pretty simple after all. So the reason it was failing on UNIX (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5) was because there was no graphical interface on this machine! No Gnome, no KDE or anything. So it was failing at a point where it tried to configure the look and feel of the application GUI. In hindsight I should have mentioned that I was using TeamCity to run these tests and I was never physically in front of the RHEL5 server.

The solution was to create a new TeamCity build which runs only GUI tests and it does this on a Windows machine.

So moral of the story, if running GUI tests on a remote machine, make sure it has graphical support!

Comment: was java.awt.headless set to true on the RHEL server? Assuming that it wasn't, you could've got a more meaningful error message. It should be set to true in a server where there is no gui. If it were, it's a problem of jgoodies to not check for that, but I would think they would check it.